# How do I toggle share button work on different posts

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

Alright, so I have share button on 6 blog posts, the toggle(show/hide) works for the first post
but when I click on share button(toggle) on second post that toggle shows on first post, it does not toggle on the second post. Kindly help. Also, I am Working on Wordpress.

[image]

[image]

Simple JS Code:

```
<script>
function remove() {
  let x = document.getElementById("social-share-inner");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: If you guys have any plugin for wordpress to add social share button on blog posts. Kindly help.

Comment: Its because you are getting the element using the id, and html page can only have one id in the web page. Use combination of parent and sibling selectors using javascript to select nearest share container to be shown to the user

Comment: First of all you have to change your function name because java script is case sensitive language it is considering the remove() as a method

Comment: @PrathameshKoshti I have changed all the ID's to simply class names. But my JS is not working idk why. CODE:-           function myFunction() {
  let x = document.getElementsByClassName("social-share-inner");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}

Comment: I am not aware of the document structure, the best way you can do is utilize the parentNode and childNodes property for the selected element, the code you mentioned above is wrong because it will return array of elements. If you are able to provide the document structure I can help you with it

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using a id here. The id refers to one element and shoulld be unique

```js
function toggle(selector) {
  let x = document.querySelectorAll(selector)[0];
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body> 
  <ul>
    <li id="post-1">
      <div>
        <button onClick="toggle('#post-1 .social-share-inner')">Toggle</button>
        <ul class="social-share-inner">
          <li>Facebook</li>
          <li>Twitter</li>
          <li>Instagram</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
     <li id="post-2">
      <div>
        <button onClick="toggle('#post-2 .social-share-inner')">Toggle</button>
        <ul class="social-share-inner">
          <li>Facebook</li>
          <li>Twitter</li>
          <li>Instagram</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body> 
</html>
```

Try it like this

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, but I am using wordpress i can't add different ID's like post 1 and 2.